# How to create an executable RAR file?

Tags: windows, winrar

Recently I downloaded on portable freeware software, which was in rar format,
which I could run with a double click and also could extract in some folder-> search for the exe file and then run it ..

observed thing is Running the project directly took same time as of extract and run, do you know this special ability of rar?

Google search with keywords "executable rar, rar exe" etc aren't fruitful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When raring the file or files, you can check "create self extracting archive" to create an exe file that will extract itself.

I would add a screenshot, but I only have a German version of Winrar, so that won't be of much use.

Comment: thanks for the useful info. :) though I couldn't find Self-Extract property while archiving with winrar. but the keyword self-extract sounds significant. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking of an executable generated by something like WinRAR that packs some tools to extract the contents inside the executable (so you have two things packed -- the tools and also the files you want to extract). 7-zip can also do this for 7z files (but not RAR).

Your question is slightly unclear, I'm not sure what the second paragraph is trying to say. If you are wanting to know what programs support this function: WinRAR (shareware) for RAR and 7-zip for 7z. There are probably more too.

Comment: In the second line I have tried to tell more about the executable rar file that I have used recently. Rar can be used as executable, double clicking on which gets a program started running. thanks regards.

Comment: yes, and that's what i'm referring to.